# Redireccionar a una página en un SweetAlert

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Tengo éste código que muestra una ventana de Sweet Alert, pero me gustaría que cuando le de clic en OK me direccione al Index o X página.

```
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
              jQuery(function(){
                swal("type: "success",
                      title: "¡Bien!",
                      text: "Pasale",
                      footer: "<a href>Regresar</a>"
                     );
              });
           </script>';
} else{
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
              jQuery(function(){
                swal("¡Error!", "Por favor, verifica los datos e intenta de nuevo", 
                     "warning"
                    );
                });
          </script>"';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta de esta manera... La función `.then` redirige después de que el usuario hace click en el botón. Debes cambiar `index.php` por la URL a la que quieres redirigir

```
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        jQuery(function(){
            swal({type: "success",
                title: "¡Bien!",
                text: "Pasale"
            }).then(function() {
                window.location = "index.php";
            });
        });
} else{
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          jQuery(function(){
            swal("¡Error!", "Por favor, verifica los datos e intenta de nuevo", 
                 "warning"
                );
            });
      </script>"';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código:

```
jQuery(function(){   
       swal({
             title: "¡Bien!",
             text: "Pasale",
             type: "success",
             //timer: 3000
        }, 
        function(){
             window.location.href = "/";
        })
 });
```